# In ncurses, is there a simple way to use every combination of the 8 standard foreground and background colors?

Tags: unix, ncurses

I've noticed that (at least on my platform) COLOR_PAIRS is 64. I've read that color pair 0 is always the default foreground and background color, and cannot be changed. With 8 default colors, this means that we can explicitly set every combination of these 8 colors except one. This is a problem for me, as the user may not necessarily have a white-on-black terminal as I do. Another potential problem for me is that I have a transparent terminal, and color pair 0 retains the transparent background, while using an explicitly color pair with a black background does not appear transparent on my terminal.

Is there a way to either use all 64 combinations of colors that may not be mentioned by the crappy documentation for ncurses that I keep finding around the net? Or is it safe to change COLOR_PAIRS to 128 before initializing the library to extend the number of colors pairs I can use? If I can't find a reasonable solution, I may just use Termbox in my program. I'd like to use ncurses for its wide support and the fact that most Unix like platforms include it by default, but Termbox has a FAR simpler API.

Comment: Yes, I'm having the same problem. Using `use_default_colors` to enable transparent background and default foreground gives me a grand total of 9x9 = 81 potential color pairs, but I only have 64 color pairs (possibly even less) to play around with, which is a problem as I'd like to support arbitrary combinations. This sucks, lol.

Answer (score 1):

With [ncurses6](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/announce.html#h3-config-config) ([August 2015](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/NEWS.html#t20150808)), the default configuration provides for 256 colors, 32767 color pairs.  If you have a current version of ncurses, you can get 64 color pairs easily enough.

[`TermBox`](https://godoc.org/github.com/nsf/termbox-go) may have a simpler API, but (read the [source-code](https://github.com/nsf/termbox-go)) is less capable, and apparently not under active development (last source-code change 8 months ago).